# Disable the "Search Google for" in Chrome context menu

Tags: google-chrome

After a fair amount of searching I have been unable to find a solid answer on how to disable, or remove, the "Search Google for..." option in the Chrome context menu. I am unable to find any options related to it within the browser itself or within the preferences file in the AppData/local/Google/Chrome/UserData/Default directory. Is this even possible or is there a manifest/config file I am completely missing? Currently on Chrome Version 79.03945.117 - Feedback or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to remove the menu item, but I found if you change your search provider to X, the menu option changes to "Search X for...".

I was also able to create a fake search provider in Chrome Settings and set it as the default for both searches from the location bar, and searches from the context menu.  I searched settings for "search", clicked "Add" next to Other search engines, and entered "localhost" as the name and keyword and http://127.0.0.1/search/%s for the Query URL. I then clicked "make default" on this search engine. Note: if you do this all searches will fail since there's not a real search engine at localhost; the point of doing it for me is to prevent any accidental searching when I have highlighted text that contains, say, a password, that I don't want to send to the Internet.